# MyBatis TooManyResultsException for seemingly correct mapping

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis

For the sake of resolving this problem I have pared down a lot of my code.

I continue to get this error as I try different things to get this collection working:

> nested exception is
>   org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.TooManyResultsException: Expected one
>   result (or null) to be returned by selectOne(), but found: 2

Relevant objects are as follows:

```
class Recipe {
    String name
    List<RecipeIngredient> ingredients
}
class RecipeIngredient {
    Double measurementAmount
}
```

I have an interface with my method call:

```
public interface CookbookDao {
    public Recipe getRecipe(@Param("id")int id)
}
```

And my result mapper:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="cookbook.daos.CookbookDao">
    <select id="getRecipe" resultMap="Recipe">
        SELECT
          r.name,
          ri.measurement_amount
        FROM
          recipe r
          INNER JOIN recipe_ingredient ri on ri.recipe_id = r.id
        WHERE
          r.id = #{id}
    </select>

    <resultMap id="Recipe" type="cookbook.domain.Recipe">
        <result property="name" column="r.name" />
        <collection property="ingredients" ofType="cookbook.domain.RecipeIngredient">
            <result property="measurementAmount" column="ri.measurement_amount"/>
        </collection>
    </resultMap>
</mapper>
```

The query returns the following results (Note: While the above code only has "measurement_amount" I've included what the actual, end-result set looks like to help show why I want/need to get these 2 rows back):

```
 name | measurement_amount | name | abbreviation | name  
------+--------------------+------+--------------+-------
 Rice |                  1 | cup  |              | rice
 Rice |                  2 | cups |              | water
```

I can get the mapper to work when I take the collection out.
I have tried using javaType and I have tried using the composite key in the collection, but it still didn't work. I have run out ideas and have looked in a ton of help posts but nothing stood out.

I'm using Spring Boot with UTD versions of mybatis and mybatis-spring

Comment: Your object map looks like it is trying to insert multiple records into a single object. Either the class resultMap needs to change to an object with a collection or the query needs to return a single result. Is the table you have with multiple Rice what you expect as a result?

Comment: @TahTatsumoto I updated the results in my original question to show why there are 2 rows returns. Imagine a Recipe in real life - there are multiple ingredients. So the relational table returns multiple rows from RecipeIngredient per each recipe queried.
The Recipe object that I am mapping to _does_ have a List type, so it - assumedly -  should map the collection there, as far as I've understood nested collections to work.

Comment: Not sure, but how should MyBatis recognize that both your rows are **one** recipe with two ingredients and not **two** recipes with one ingredient each? First thing I would try is to set the name as id instead of simply `<result...>`: `<id property="name" column="r.name"/>` to give it at least a chance to do so.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz Hmm. My understanding is that MyBatis infers from the specified "type" object the particular structure of what you're returning, including the presence of a list or collection. Ultimately, this is a one-to-many relationship, which shows up as multiple rows when you query in MySQL. I assumed that the whole point of MyBatis is to make that mapping of a one-to-many relationship very simple, so it should ... just... work.

 -  I have tried using an <id ... > as well, with no luck.

Comment: Surprisingly enough, the whole thing actually works for me (which I didn't expect). I just had to remove the r. and ri. prefixes (from <result), but that's probably just because MySql doesn't use them for the names. Unfortunately, I didn't even get your error, when the prefixes were there, but just NO ingredients. But in the end, I got one recipe (with your code): `[Recipe [name=Rice, ingredients=[RecipeIngredient [measurementAmount=1.0], RecipeIngredient [measurementAmount=2.0]]]]` Kinda asking myself now, how I would map the case if one row was actually one result, with non-unique names...

Comment: So, good news everyone... Your code works. Just not for you. Erm. Sorry. Versions are Spring Boot 1.3.2, MyBatis 3.3.0, MyBatis 1.2.3 and mybatis-spring-boot-starter 1.0

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz It works!! You solved it, despite not knowing it. The problem is that I was accessing the columns with their table aliases, and apparently MyBatis doesn't understand that. SO - I aliased each column with a unique name and it worked like a charm! Thanks for helping me along :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that MyBatis doesn't understand my associations with aliased tables, so I changed my query to:

```
SELECT
  r.name as recipe_name,
  ri.measurement_amount as measurement_amount
FROM
  recipe r
  INNER JOIN recipe_ingredient ri on ri.recipe_id = r.id
WHERE
  r.id = #{id}
```

and updated the mapper to use the alias for column (recipe_name instead of ri.name, etc), as such:

```
<resultMap id="Recipe" type="cookbook.domain.Recipe">
    <result property="name" column="recipe_name" />
    <collection property="ingredients" ofType="cookbook.domain.RecipeIngredient">
        <result property="measurementAmount" column="measurement_amount"/>
    </collection>
</resultMap>
```

and it worked!

Thanks to those who commented to help

Comment: how would you do using annotations?

Answer (score -2):

you can try use `List`.

```
public interface CookbookDao {
    public List<Recipe> getRecipe(@Param("id")int id);
}
```